# Can not change state value before submitting in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using one of react phone input library and getting the value of phone number is in "+9901231231234" format . I want only last ten value is in integer form. So i am converting them in number.

```
if (this.validator.allValid()) {

    const phnNo = this.state.phone // +9901231231234
    if(phnNo.length>10){
      var lastTen = phnNo.substr(phnNo.length - 10);
    const  subphone = Number(lastTen) //1231231234

      this.setState({ phone: subphone }) // Now I want to set the this.state.phone =  1231231234
      alert(this.state.phone)  // +9901231231234 
    }
  } else {
    this.validator.showMessages();


    // rerender to show messages for the first time
    // you can use the autoForceUpdate option to do this automatically`
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

But I can not change the current state value with the new value i am generating.Thank you.

Comment: @Treycos is correct. But if you are passing the `subphone` in the alert why not just pass that variable to `alert`? I understand needing it in state for some later use, but it seems you can just pass that to the `alert` itself without having to add a callback to `setState`.

Comment: setState is async
Your alert should be placed in the callback of setState: ``this.setState({ phone: subphone },()=>{alert(this.state.phone)})``

Answer (score 4):

The `setState` function will not update your values synchronously, your state will not be changed right away. The second parameter of it allows you to give a callback function triggering when the state has been mutated :

```
  this.setState({ phone: subphone }, () => { alert(this.state.phone) //1231231234 })
```